# Get raw data when importing a package dynamically

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, dynamic-import

So while working on a react project i have a requirement of getting the dynamically imported package data in raw format (`text/plain`) instead of `default:javascript format`

For example:

```js
await import(package_name).then(module => {do_something(module.default)})
```

but i dont want this to be converted in js but the raw data that is recieved from server of requested package, Anyone can share ideas/solution on this problem, can be aa huge help

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) instead of `import()` which will return the raw data.

Comment: Hmm i thought about that already but can you help me in terms of url, like where do i import it from , cause when we import any package from import function/operator we don't specify the url

Comment: @KRISHNANPANDYA but you do specify a path, I think, something like `import('/modules/my-module.js')`?

Comment: @GrafiCode , so i am using react, so my modules are in node_modules folder can you give some brief idea about how to make this flow work, it'll be a great help for me!!,Thanks BTW

Comment: you can use fetch with the path of your file, something like `fetch('/node_modules/path/to/file.js')`

Comment: @GrafiCode Hmm, i've tried that looks like thats can't be fethed as its outside of public folder, however if i make a copy of that package and move it to public folder, it works...